# illegal base64 data at input byte 4852 with sealed secrets

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I have this secret built like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secrets
type: Opaque
stringData:
  PORT: "3000"
  MONGODB_HOSTNAME: hostname
  MONGODB_USER: fares
  MONGODB_PASSWORD: password
  MONGODB_TEST_HOSTNAME: localhost
  ENCODED_CREDENTIALS: ewog...
```

`ENCODED_CREDENTIALS` contains an encoded base64 JSON file. It's decoded in the app but I need it to remain encoded as a secret.

Now, I seal it using my cert and `kubeseal`, but ArgoCD displays this:  `ErrUnsealFailed - Failed to unseal: illegal base64 data at input byte 4852`.

I feel like it's the fact that `ENCODED_CREDENTIALS` is already encoded that might be a problem, but I'm not sure.

Are you guys familiar with this kind of problems?

TIA

**EDIT**:

The decoding (pre-seal) works:

```
echo -n $test_thing | base64 -d
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "blabla",
  "private_key_id": "blabla",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
             ...
\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "john.doe@gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "abcd1234",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/bucket-sa%40steve-jobs.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

It's only when it seals & unseals with the sealed secrets controller that it fails.

Comment: So have you looked at byte 4852 of your encoded credentials?

Comment: Yeah, it's "U".

Comment: Hmm... that should be fine in base64. Have you put the complete text of it through a "regular" base64 decoder (obviously not an online one, but in Python, Java, C#, Go, whatever)?

Comment: Yep, I used my shell decoder (`base64 -d`) and I'm getting the expected JSON string, as you can see in the edit section of my post.

Comment: Right. In that case it's beyond me, I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 0):

Good news!

I've managed to find where the issue is.

For some reason, adding an (intentionally) encoded value to `stringData` keys breaks the unsealing process.

For those who are curious, I've raised the bug (?) to the sealed secrets team: [#1038](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets/issues/1038)